# Cisco ASA: Windows DHCP doesn't bind IP address after failover change active

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, dhcp, failover, cisco-anyconnect

**Equipment and soft:**

- Two Cisco ASA 5540, ASA ver. 9.1(7)32, active/standby failover
- DHCP server: Windows server 2016

Anyconnect VPN clients get IP addresses from DHCP servers. Everything works properly until change active/standby ASA.
Current VPN-connections still work, but new clients cannot get IP addresses. DHCP server logs:

```
IP address range of scope TEST_VPN is out of IP addresses.
There are no IP addresses available for lease in the scope or superscope "TEST_VPN".
```

Although there are a lot of unassigned IP addresses.
After command **Reconcile All Scopes** on DHCP server it starts giving IP addresses again.

I would like failover to operate without any problems. What should I do?

Comment: You need to add your sanitized ASA configuration for us to help you. Servers are off topic on Network Engineering.

Comment: If Reconcile Scope helps you did run out of IP addresses - this is badly managed on Windows. Troubleshoot the issue on the server, off-topic here.